# Problems with BR keyboard in dell mini

Tags: keyboard

I need a help, because I'm newbie in Linux and I'm trying to configure the  keyboard for this Dell mini, but some keys don't work, such as: |, Alt Gr, [, ]

Thank's a lot.

[image]

Comment: Which language layout did you set?

Comment: Hi, the layout is Portuguese (Brazil).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your keyboard layout to **Portuguese (Brazil, eliminate dead keys)**. Follow these steps to change the default layout:

1. Open *System Settings* from the *Applications* menu.
2. Select *Keyboard* under the *Hardware* section.
3. Click the *Layout* button.
4. On the left side list box you will see a <kbd>+</kbd> button, click it.
5. From the *Language* drop-down box, select **Portuguese (Brazil)**. From the *Layout* drop-down box, select **Portuguese (Brazil, eliminate dead keys)**. Click **Add Layout**.
6. Highlight **Portuguese (Brazil, eliminate dead keys)** from the list box.

This should result in the proper keyboard layout.

Comment: Thank Mr.Mims, but unfortunately did not work.

Comment: The original layout is Portuguese (Brazil).

Comment: Try these settings: Language_Portuguese; Layout_English

Comment: Oh sorry! For some reason I thought it was a UK layout.

Comment: I updated the answer, I think you need the Portuguese (Brazil, eliminate dead keys) layout.