# keyboard and bank security app

Tags: keyboard, startup

My keyboard stop working properly since I installed elementary os

number six is not working in any of the keys. besides that some keys are not working in my brazil, no dead keys keyboard (I also tried in english - the original)

those are the things I tried:

[Dead keys not working on Elementary OS Loki](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10491/dead-keys-not-working-on-elementary-os-loki)

[How can I use IBus as the default input method?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2371/how-can-i-use-ibus-as-the-default-input-method)

[Problems with BR keyboard in dell mini](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/problems-with-br-keyboard-in-dell-mini?rq=1)

nothing worked

I read some place that some keyboards don't work with elementary (?), is it true?

I also could not install my bank 'security app' (I follow the bank directions for linux and also some websites in portuguese)

I would appreciate if anybody could help with one of those problems.
Thanks

my keyboard is like this one: https://exact-parts.com/collections/hp-15-bs289wm/products/hp-15-bs289wm-palmrest-keyboard-assembly-w-touchpad-925008-001#mz-expanded-view-1506610706696

Answer (score 0):

I could not fix the missing keys problem, but I found out an alternative for now. First of all, from what Ive been reading it seems to be a problem with kernel, since the keyboard works perfectly with windows (even though, windows does not works perfectly for me).

The way I fixed it was creating "phrase" shortcuts on my keyboard using autokey, but instead of a whole phrase I pasted number 6 and a few other missing keys from some old document.
And shortcuts options are pretty easy. eg: shift+/ = 6

Here is what helped me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/280604/assign-hotkeys-to-paste-predefined-text

(I still didn't fix the bank thing, but it is less important)